# Курсор в contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Если в первый раз кликнуть на `div contenteditable` то курсор становится где-то вверху, при наборе текста, он становится на правильное место. Как можно пофиксить этот момент? Что бы и в первый раз курсор ставился по середине (по вертикали)? Заранее спасибо!

Демка http://jsfiddle.net/0gr09835/1/

```css
div.msg {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  /* For Firefox */
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:focus:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Написать сообщение..." contenteditable="true"></div>
```

P.S. Баг обнаружен в FireFox в Chrome вроде нормально всё.

Comment: cursor же нормально в середине стоит

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/kUPlIVEET9qJNhoWjW8aCw.png  мой скрин

Comment: [contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
[contenteditable=true]:empty:focus:before {
    content: "";
}

Comment: не знаю на кой   тебе псевдо классы и псевдо элементы которые в комменте выше, но проблема в них

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы, не знаете как можно сделать placeholder без них или просто делать html вставку через jquery "Введите ваше сообщение" и убирать когда нужно?

Comment: а почему не input?  в чем соль?

Comment: да просто это типа чата, и в инпут не вставить картинки, смайлы...так что они в инпуте и отображались

Comment: это мне нужно вам в ЛС написать? я тут не сильно ещё разобрался)

Comment: @СергейКозин, на мой взгляд ты не прав... оберни  textarea  div-ом и стилизуй как душе угодно... но естественно решать тебе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы лично решил так....

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

div.msg {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.msg:focus~span {
  display: none;
}

span {
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="msg" name="msg" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <span>Написать сообщение...</span>
</div>
```